# VBA Error - Application-defined pr Object-defined Error When using If

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote this following code in VBA:

```
Dim Counter As Long
Dim Counter_Two As Long
Dim Array_Column_Letter(3) As String

Array_Column_Letter(0) = "A"
Array_Column_Letter(1) = "B"
Array_Column_Letter(2) = "C"
Array_Column_Letter(0) = "D"

For Counter = 0 To LastRow
  For Counter_Two = 0 To 3
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, Array_Column_Letter(Counter_Two)).Value = IsEmpty(True) Then
      MsgBox ("Hi")
    End If
  Next Counter_Two
Next Counter
```

For some reason I'm getting the following error:

> Application-defined pr Object-defined Error

VBA says there is something wrong with if statement causing this error. I can't seem to figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: your `For Counter = 0 To LastRow` starts from `0`, so `Cells(Counter, Array_Column_Letter(Counter_Two)).Value` starts from row `0`, which results with your error. You can also write this line `If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, Array_Column_Letter(Counter_Two)).Value) Then`

Comment: Just a general question - what do you think that `IsEmpty(True)` does?

Comment: `IsEmpty(True)`will always be false, so basically you are testing for the content of the cells to be false. Probably not what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ranges in Excel start at "A1" not "A0"

This line

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, Array_Column_Letter(Counter_Two)).Value = IsEmpty(True) Then
```

Should be changed to

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter + 1 , Array_Column_Letter(Counter_Two)).Value = IsEmpty(True) Then
```

Also to use isempty correctly you should use it as below

```
If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter + 1 , Array_Column_Letter(Counter_Two)).Value) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because you are trying to find row 0. Change the starting value in your first For statement